# Dropping duplicate observations with more missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have duplicated values in my df, however one of the observation has a lot of nans.
I would like to keep the duplicated value that has the lowest missing value.

Any ideas how to do this ?

This is an example of my df:

```
id    B    C    D
1     2    3    4
1     .    3    4
1     .    .    4
2     9    7    .
2     9    .    8
2     9    7    8
2     .    .    .
```

In this example I would like to keep only the first observation and the 6th.

Thanks

Comment: Is it already guaranteed that `['B', 'C', 'D']` are duplicated (with your definition of missing) within `'id'` or do you also need to verify that duplication before dropping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `df.isna().sum(axis=1)` to count the amount of `NaNs` by row, and then [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `id` and select the row with less `NaNs` using [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
df.loc[df.isna().sum(axis=1).groupby(df.id).idxmin(),:]

   id    B    C    D
0   1  2.0  3.0  4.0
5   2  9.0  7.0  8.0
```

Make sure the missing values are `NaNs` as you specified, otherwise start with:

```
df.replace('.',np.nan)
```

Comment: yup thats much better than mine

Answer (score 3):

A different approach that does more than what you asked for. This is if some values are missing in one row and different are missing in another row and you want to combine these to get more complete information:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], "B": [2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 9], "C": [3, 3, np.nan, 7, np.nan, np.nan], "D": [4, 4, 4, np.nan, 8, np.nan]})
#      B    C    D  id
# 0  NaN  3.0  4.0   1
# 1  NaN  3.0  NaN   1
# 2  NaN  NaN  4.0   1
# 3  NaN  7.0  NaN   2
# 4  NaN  NaN  8.0   2
# 5  9.0  NaN  NaN   2

df.groupby("id", as_index=False).fillna(method="bfill").drop_duplicates(subset="id")
#      B    C    D  id
# 0  NaN  3.0  4.0   1
# 3  9.0  7.0  8.0   2
```

Note that the example df is slightly different than in your question so to show off where this approach would be better.

For id 1 it is the same as just taking the first row. But for id 2 it is actually able to fill out all values, where your (or the other answers) would take just one row, all of which suck.

Obviously this assumes that the values that are not `NaN` stay the same. If they do not, only the first occurrences of NaN in that column will be taken.

---

Edit:

In newer `pandas` version (at least 1.4.2), `fillna` seems to do weird things when being applied to the grouped dataframe and drops the `id` column. You can circumvent this by using `apply`:

```py
df.groupby("id", as_index=False)\
  .apply(lambda s: s.fillna(method="bfill"))\
  .drop_duplicates(subset="id")
```

Comment: thanks for the example. However, it gives the following error as of pandas 1.4.3 `KeyError: Index(['id'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @JeroenVermunt Indeed, in newer versions the ID column seems to be dropped by the `fillna` method, not sure why...

Answer (score 2):

You can drop any row with with a certain number of NaNs with the following:

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, thresh=4)  # drop any row that has at least 4 non-nans within it.
```

`axis=0` being rows
`thresh=4` being the check. You could set this to whatever you like. You could set this to 2 so any row with 2 or more NaNs will be dropped.